# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: stock_name

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

```
#user_input.py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)


def process_user_input(data):
    
    # Retrieve user input from the data
    stock_name = data.get('stockName')

    # Create a new connection and cursor
    conn = sqlite3.connect('C:/SQLite/pythonstock/database.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute("SELECT price FROM stocks WHERE lower(stockName) = ?", (stock_name.lower(),))

    # Fetch the result
    row = c.fetchone()
    if row:
        price = row[0]  # Access the first column (price)
        # Perform further operations with the retrieved price
    else:
        # Handle the case when no row is found for the given stock_name
        price = None  # or any appropriate default value or error handling

    # Close the cursor and connection
    c.close()
    conn.close()

    processed_input = price

    # Create a JSON-serializable response
    response = {'processed_input': processed_input}
    return response
def process_user_input1(data):
    print("Process_user_input1 started")
    # Retrieve user input from the data
    stock_name = data.get('stockName')
    BRstage=data.get('BRstage')
   
   
    # Create a new connection and cursor
    conn = sqlite3.connect('C:/SQLite/pythonstock/database.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('update stocks set BRstage=BRstage where stockName=stock_name')
   
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    processed_input1='success'
    response = {'processed_input1': processed_input1}
    return response

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1455, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 869, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 176, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 867, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 852, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Steven\stock.investing.decision.making\my-app\flask-app\main.py", line 25, in process_user_input_route1   
    result = process_user_input1(data)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Steven\stock.investing.decision.making\my-app\flask-app\user_input.py", line 57, in process_user_input1   
    c.execute('UPDATE stocks SET BRstage = ? WHERE lower(stockName) = ?', (BRstage, stock_name.lower()))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: stock_name
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2023 22:11:41] "POST /process_user_input1 HTTP/1.1" 500 -


 File "c:\Users\Steven\stock.investing.decision.making\my-app\flask-app\user_input.py", line 57, in process_user_input1
    c.execute('UPDATE stocks SET BRstage = ? WHERE lower(stockName) = ?', (BRstage, stock_name.lower()))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: stock_name
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2023 23:21:36] "POST /process_user_input1 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Answer (score 1):

`stockName` is a database column.
`stock_name` is a python variable.

Compare these two:

```
c.execute("SELECT price FROM stocks WHERE lower(stockName) = ?", (stock_name.lower(),))

c.execute('update stocks set BRstage=BRstage where stockName=stock_name')
```

In the former, the value of the `stock_name` variable is converted to lower case and then passed to the execute() method, for substitution into the SQL command.  (BTW, that lower(stockName) will kill your performance as the dataset grows).

In the latter, the name `stock_name` is embedded in the SQL command and sqlite tries - and fails - to resolve it to a column name.

Comment: File "c:\Users\Steven\stock.investing.decision.making\my-app\flask-app\user_input.py", line 57, in process_user_input1
    c.execute('UPDATE stocks SET BRstage = ? WHERE lower(stockName) = ?', (BRstage, stock_name.lower()))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: stock_name
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2023 23:21:36] "POST /process_user_input1 HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Comment: How to solve it?